# How to Change Variable Value on new line in Php

Tags: php, list

Here i have single line of variable value. You can see here below in php source code

```
<?php

$list = "03343922581 03136011388 03142181356 03471819024 03003973577";

//Please tell me the php code

?>
```

**I want to get output like below**

```
03343922581  
03136011388   
03142181356   
03471819024   
03003973577
```

Comment: I assume you need to echo it then...

Comment: `echo nl2br($list);`

Comment: I have cleared my question description. Please help me  MorganFreeFarm, Andreas ,u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

for show result in html page according to your desire you can use :

```
$new_list = str_replace(" ","\n",$list);
echo nl2br($new_list);
```

Comment: Dear Majid If i want to place every new line value in the new row of table how do I do it.

Comment: it is very general question. you can read this [https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp]  and also this [https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp]